# Magento disable auto shipping quote on cart

Tags: php, magento

In magento I would like to remove the auto shipping calculation.  Currently if you entered in a zip code to calculate, go back to shopping and add more to cart, when you go back to the cart it will automatically calculate shipping.   I would like to require that the "Get Quote" button be pressed to calculate shipping every time.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same since a week but its not working 100%. I think the code should be like this:

Step one: Add a JS function:

```
_instantQuoteShippingResponse {
    var cart = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-shipping-block')[0];
    cart.innerHTML = response.responseText.evalJSON().cart_shipping;
    cart.innerHTML = cart.firstChild.innerHTML;
    return true;
}

instantQuoteShipping() {
    try {var request = new Ajax.Request(coShippingMethodForm.form.action, {method: 'post',
            parameters: {
                country_id: $('country').value, region_id: $('region_id').value,
                region: $('region').value, estimate_postcode: $('postcode').value},
                redirect: 'no',
            onSuccess: function(response) {_instantQuoteShippingResponse(response);},
            onFailure: function(response) {coShippingMethodForm.submit();}});
    } catch(e) { return false;}
    return true;
}
```

Step two: add click event to shipping quote button (app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\checkout\cart\shipping.phtml).

```
onclick="instantQuoteShipping()"
```

Step three: edit cart controller (Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php)
rewrite estimatePostAction:

```
public function estimatePostAction()
{
    parent::estimatePostAction();
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('redirect') == 'no') {
        try {
            $response = array();
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
            // $response['cart_shipping'] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart.shipping')->toHtml();
            $response['cart_shipping'] = $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('checkout/cart_shipping')
                ->setTemplate('checkout/cart/shipping.phtml')->toHtml();
            $this->getResponse()->clearAllHeaders();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($response));
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Step four: edit cart.phtml (app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\checkout\cart.phtml) copy all content from shipping.phtml, except estimate rate block:

```
// Locate this line:
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>

// Update to...:
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): ?>
    // Paste all content from shipping.phtml here
<?php endif; ?>


// ATENTION: Dont paste the code below
if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())) {
    ...
}
```

It should work!

Comment: search brought me here, did you ever happen to get this working 100%?